# interesting project Ignoring exit condition on first candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

```
In a strategy with entry and exit conditions, is it possible to set a conditional expression that ignores the exit condition in the first candle where the entry occurs?
```

That is, the exit condition is activated from the second candle

I'm new to PineScript, so I'm learning this and that. I'd appreciate it if you could teach me your knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` to get the entry bar index.

Below code will give you the number of bars since the entry.

```
bars_since_entry = bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)
```

Then use `bars_since_entry` as condition for your exit.

Comment: It seems that you are the only one here hahahaha